# I want to configure postfix to use a relay smtp server, so that drupal uses postfix, but I don't know how to do it and I'm trying all I know

Tags: email, postfix, smtp, drupal

### Objective

I want to be able to send emails with drupal 8 using postfix. The latter is configured to use a relay server.
For example, I'm using the module webforms, so I could test the sending of emails

### All that I have done

```
sudo apt install postfix
```

During the installation I selected

- Internet Site
- System mail name: gonzalonazareno.org

Inside `/etc/postfix/main.cf` I changed

```
myhostname = drupal.gonzalonazareno.org
relayhost = babuino-smtp.gonzalonazareno.org
```

After this I restarted postfix, and tested postfix with this

```
echo "body of your email" | mail -s "This is a Subject" -a "From: test@example.com" test@gonzalonazareno.org
```

But when I send an email I get nothing

### Important notes

- Some information here may not have sense, because I'm pretty lost with this task. All I know, is that I need to send an email, using postfix, and that relay server. Postfix will send the email to the relay, but after that, I don't really know if that email stores the messages...etc. Also, I don't know how to make drupal send that email, I can't figure out how can it do it.
- I think that you can test the smtp server I need to use `babuino-smtp.gonzalonazareno.org`, and check if maybe it's having problems

### Post Data

My apologies if this question is confusing, but my understanding of email servers if pretty basic + I'm really lost

Answer (score 0):

### SOLUTION

I had 2 main problems

- The SMTP server I was using`babuino-smtp.gonzalonazareno.org` was only accessible via the intranet of our highschool, so postfix couldn't communicate with it
- After all the postfix configuration, I was trying to test if it worked with the following command

```
echo "body of your email" | mail -s "This is a Subject" -a "From: test@example.com" test@gonzalonazareno.org
```

Which was wrong, because I figured out that you cannot send an email to a non-existing address `test@gonzalonazareno.org` (maybe you can, but then how could you check the email?)

After all, when I came to class today and I was connected to the intranet, email sending was working. The command above worked, and also drupal could send an email (using the contact module for forms). I did both tests with my gmail account of course

---

Now, I would really appreciate if someone that knows how all this stuff works could complete the information about how drupal knows how to communicate with postfix. Because yep, it worked for me, but I just configured drupal to use a smtp server, and to send forms to a @gmail.com recipient.
I configured literally nothing for something like "making drupal choose what to use for sending emails"
Does this come pre-configured with drupal? I would like to know it if possible